# AWS Pub/Sub Message Pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, microservices

Can someone explain to me the advantage or disadvantage of using SNS -> Lambda  vs. SNS -> SQS -> Lambda.

I'm looking to setup an architecture for pub/sub micro-service messaging, but having a queue in front of every Lambda seems excessive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless something has changed, the question of whether to it makes more sense to deploy SNS → Lambda, or SNS → SQS → Lambda, is based on a premise with a significant flaw.

As is indicated in [Supported Event Sources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html) in the Lambda documentation, Lambda events can be sourced from S3, DynamoDB, Kinesis, SNS, SES, Cognito, CloudFormation, CloudWatch & Events (including Scheduled Events), AWS Config, Amazon Echo, and API Gateway.

And, of course, you can invoke them directly.

But SQS is not a supported Lambda event source.

Comment: You are correct and I apologize for miss statement on direct trigger, Lambda in the case of queue would require polling with a schedule lambda.  But I guess i'm looking for how do you get at least once delivery with SNS to Lambda

Comment: @tafaju SNS will always invoke a subscribed Lambda function. If your Lambda function doesn't complete successfully it will be retried up to twice more. But your Lambda function will always get invoked at least once. With SNS to Lambda the downside is that there is no concept of a dead-letter queue, so if your Lambda function times out three times for the same SNS message then you've just dropped that data on the floor. No way to recover.

Comment: @idbehold is correct.  One workaround to avoid lost data if three-sreikes errors prevent the events from processing would be to fan-out from an SNS topic to both Lambda and SQS, letting the messages normally just expire and be automatically purged from the SQS queue unless Lambda errors are logged, in which case a cleanup process could review the enqueued messages.  I have an S3 > SNS > Lambda setup that does this.  The Lambda function sometimes throws errors when S3 is one of its "eventually consistent" moods during large batches of overwrites of existing objects, so this is my fallback plan.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon SQS is a message queue service used by distributed applications to exchange messages through a polling model, and can be used to decouple sending and receiving components—without requiring each component to be concurrently available. By using Amazon SNS and Amazon SQS together, messages can be delivered to applications that require immediate notification of an event, and also persisted in an Amazon SQS queue for other applications to process at a later time.

Untill you don't want to decouple sending and receiving components and just want to achieve your use case in the question it will work in both case SNS- Lambda and SNS - SQS - Lambda.

Comment: I agree both are achievable, just looking for specific pros/cons in context of building a reliable message platform.  The only item I can see being an issue is reliability which would be missing in the SNS  -> Lambda context since SQS would provide reliable processing and retry attempts.

Comment: And Durability too as it will make sure each and every message is delivered to Lambda atleast once

Comment: Yes for SNS SQS and Lambda

Comment: just found a post that SNS => Lambda is also at-least-once; https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=614191